# gulp-fontgen виснет при выполнении

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Задача сгенерировать при помощи плагина [gulp-fontgen](https://github.com/agentk/gulp-fontgen/) готовый `font-face`.

**Код из gulpfile.js:**

```
gulp.task(
'fonts', ['del-fonts'], function(){
    gulp.src(path.src.fonts)
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: onError})) // plumber
        .pipe(gulpfontgen({
            /*collate: true,
            css_fontpath: path.src.fontface,*/
            dest: path.build.fonts
        }))
        .pipe(plumber.stop())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.fonts))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream:true }))
        .pipe(notify({message: 'FONTS task complete', onLast: true}));
});
```

После запуска пробовал ждать до 30 минут, безрезультатно, пока не прерываю задачу.
Папка со шрифтами не генерируется.

**Консоль:**

> [11:23:14] Using gulpfile e:\OpenServer\domains\devboilerplate\gulpfile.js
>   [11:23:14] Starting 'del-fonts'...
>   [11:23:14] Finished 'del-fonts' after 8.47 ms
>   [11:23:14] Starting 'fonts'...
>   [11:23:14] Finished 'fonts' after 19 ms
>   ^CЗавершить выполнение пакетного файла [Y(да)/N(нет)]? y

Кто встречал подобное? Какие-нибудь советы?

Если есть другой плагин как альтернатива или кто-то знает как ипользовать нодовский [fontfacegen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fontfacegen) внутри gulpjs файла готов рассмотреть альтернативы.

Comment: Вы забыли вернуть поток из gulp таска.

Comment: добавил return.
Все равно висит, только теперь не пишет, что закончено.